# How update array in real time not after refresh page (Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, local-storage, jsx

I'm doing to do list and want do the functional when you click on button "done" the text will be crossed out.
I done array with deals which have fields 'text' and 'isDone'. isDone by default is false, when on click I get all array with deals and text deal in which you click. Than I map array with deals that I get and compare text from click deal and text in all deals in array.If they the same I change isDone from false to true.
But it update if i refresh the page and I need that it updata on click.
I use redux-persist and all states put into localStorage

button

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.done(this.props.deals,value.text)}>Done</button>
```

Action

```
export function done(newDeals,dealText){
    return(dispatch) =>{
        newDeals.map(value=>{
            if(value.text === dealText){
                value.isDone = !value.isDone
            }
        })
        dispatch(doneDeal(newDeals));
    }
}

export function doneDeal(newDeals){
    return{
        type: DONE,
        newDeals
    }
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function toDoList(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case DONE:
            return { 
                ...state, deals: action.newDeals
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I delete code that have no sense for this example, but need more info please ask I will tell
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mapStateToProps to get the recently updated state from Redux state.

All what you need is to wrap your component export with the following:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    deals: state.deals
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);
```

By this you are getting the needed state data from the initialState you have defined in your reducer and the reference to these data is the "deals" which can be used as normal prop: `this.props.deals` in case of class component OR as parameter through descructureing `({deals})` in case of functional component.

I don't know the full structure of the component because you haven't added it but this is the correct way to get the state from redux.

To make things more clear for you, you can read more through this link:
https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate

---

UPDATE: I figured out your problem after adding your reply.
The problem is with your code here:
`<button onClick={()=>this.props.done(this.props.deals,value.text)}>Done</button>`

You are getting the deals directly from the Redux global state and when dispatching your action you are passing them directly in the dispatch method. So your component is not able to listen to any change happening to your component. You need to save the deals in your local state:

```
state = {
    deals: this.props.deals
}
```

and change the onClick to the following:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.props.done(this.state.deals,value.text)}>Done</button>
```

Comment: I get the array in Component `function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        value: state.ListInput.value,
        deals: state.ListInput.deals,
        isDone: state.ListInput.isDone,
    }
}` and map it , nd I rewrite it on reducer on click button.And it is wirk but after refresh page

Comment: @Volodumr, I have updated my answer after adding your reply which make the issue more clear.

Comment: I try your variant but there still the same problem

Comment: add value and isDone as well to the local state of the component:

state = {
    deals: this.props.deals,
    value: this.props. value,
    isDone: this.props. isDone
}

and then use the local state through: this.state.value and this.state.isDone instead of:
this.props.value and this.props.isDone